# Angular2 Error: Return type of public method from exported class has or is using private name

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I am building out an Angular 2 app using the Angular-CLI, after initially building a working version of the app using the non-CLI version of Angular 2. To my surprise, some code that wasn't a problem in my non-CLI app version HAS been a problem with my Angular-CLI version. All that said, I've resolved everything except for one final error I am stuck on.

This is the error message I'm getting:

> Uncaught Error: Module build failed: Error:
>   /Users/fdr/Documents/rds/rds/cli-rds/src/app/ui/generate-field.component.ts
>   (340,48): Return type of public method from exported class has or is
>   using private name 'Hint'.)

And here is the problem file causing the error:

```
import { Component, Input, Output, EventEmitter, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { EventHandler } from '../app.event-handler';
import  '../app.utils';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-generate-field',
    templateUrl: 'app/ui/generate-field.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['app/ui/generate-field.component.css']

})
export class GenerateField extends EventHandler
{

    public get hasFocus(): boolean
    {
        return this._hasFocus;
    }

    @Input() delay: number = 300;


    @ViewChild('inputField') private inputField: ElementRef;


    @ViewChild('suggestionField') private suggestionField: ElementRef;


    @Input() public value: string;


    @Output() private valueChange: EventEmitter<string> = new EventEmitter<string>();


    @Output() public keyup: EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent> = new EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent>();

    @Output() public focus = new EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent>();

    @Output() public blur = new EventEmitter<KeyboardEvent>();

    private inlineSuggestion: string;

    private suggestions: ISuggestion[];

    @Input() public options: string[];

    @Output() private optionsChange: EventEmitter<string[]> = new EventEmitter<string[]>();

    private isDirty: boolean = false;

    private _hasFocus: boolean = false;


    constructor(myElement: ElementRef)
    {
        super();


        this.defineObservableProperty('value');
        this.defineObservableProperty('isDirty');
        this.defineObservableProperty('suggestions');
        this.defineObservableProperty('options');

        this.addPropertyListener('isDirty', function ()
        {
            if (this.isDirty == false)return;

            var delay = this.delay ? this.delay : 500;

            var self = this;

            setTimeout(function ()
            {
                self.updateSuggestions();

                this.isDirty = false;

            }.bind(this), delay);

        }.bind(this));

        this.addPropertyListener('value', (): void=>
        {
            this.valueChange.emit(this.value);

            this.isDirty = true;
        });

        this.addPropertyListener('suggestions', (): void=>
        {
            this.updateInlineSuggestion();
        });

        this.addPropertyListener('options', ()=>
        {
            this.optionsChange.emit(this.options);
        });

    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------
    // Functions
    //--------------------------------------------------------

    /**
     * Evaluates value and updates the list of suggestions
     */
    public updateSuggestions(): void
    {
        // Update suggestions
        this.suggestions = this.generateSuggestions(this.value);
    }

    /***
     * Updates the inline suggestion that appears on the text field
     */
    private updateInlineSuggestion(): void
    {
        // Clear inline if there are no suggestions
        if (this.suggestions.length == 0)
        {
            this.inlineSuggestion = '';
            return;
        }

        // Show first option inline
        this.inlineSuggestion = this.suggestions[0].value;

        var x = this.inputField.nativeElement.selectionStart;
        var y = this.inputField.nativeElement.selectionEnd;

        this.suggestionField.nativeElement.selectionStart = x;
        this.suggestionField.nativeElement.selectionEnd = y;

        this.inputField.nativeElement.selectionStart = x;
        this.inputField.nativeElement.selectionEnd = y;

        this.suggestionField.nativeElement.scrollLeft = x;

    }

    private onFocus(): void
    {
        this._hasFocus = true;

        // Forward event
        this.focus.emit();
    }

    private onBlur(): void
    {
        this._hasFocus = false;

        // Forward event
        this.blur.emit();
    }


interface ISuggestion
{

    word: string;

    match: string;

    value: string;
}
```

Comment: and have you checked if `ISuggestion` is private? If yes, why did you make it private?

Comment: I didn't write this part of the code - another dev did. I'm looking through the code now.

Comment: I did find this one reference in the file:
private suggestions: ISuggestion[];

Comment: Changing it to "public suggestions: ISuggestion[];" did not resolve the issue. And I'm curious - if this is the problem code - why is it a problem in an Angular-CLI version, but not a standard Angular 2 version? Just trying to understand. Also, how would you suggest I edit this code if not merely setting it to "public"? Thanks.

Comment: The error is not about `suggestions` to be private but about `ISuggestion` to be private.

Comment: I cannot find anywhere where ISuggestion is explicitly set to private. And I've looked for all occurrences of ISuggestion throughout the entire app.

Comment: There can only be one single place, that's where `ISuggestion` is declared.

Comment: I've looked through then entire file listed above thoroughly, and I don't see anywhere where it's explicitly declared. What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to add "**export** interface ISuggestion" at the last part of your code so that ISuggestion is exported, too.

Comment: At first I thought this didn't resolve the issue, but actually it did. So thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try adding : any after your method. I encountered same problem, It solved after I added any.